# Give multiple dictionaries can I get the lowest(or highest)value for each key?

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to approach this problem but given the following dict:

```
{'diff': {0: 358438.3179047619, 1: 2877912.924419369, 2: 822017.9039274186, 3: 4914425.223282051, 4: 574184.9971827588, 5: 7432268.5341428565, 6: 1111639.5132252753, 7: 1322861.412610346, 8: 1179799.2592362808, 9: 87556.64146904761}}
{'diff': {0: 292811.4124761905, 1: 2831096.9336261265, 2: 760006.755798387, 3: 4868369.423293451, 4: 509515.30310344836, 5: 7390444.080714285, 6: 1028933.0801098899, 7: 1240273.4906724147, 8: 1138039.7093932922, 9: 43618.81660000001}}
{'diff': {0: 393148.40700238093, 1: 2923931.0134306327, 2: 878450.4552137096, 3: 4962539.102763245, 4: 660218.1550965513, 5: 7483527.590967346, 6: 1223029.819152747, 7: 1372622.6893804593, 8: 1202322.4719079277, 9: 113611.58858809523}}
{'diff': {0: 386402.65016666666, 1: 2916900.423062612, 2: 870947.0239475806, 3: 4954526.795990028, 4: 652106.3039551723, 5: 7475754.573836735, 6: 1212934.2664368134, 7: 1365836.4194977009, 8: 1196003.2297920743, 9: 108039.20073571429}}
{'diff': {0: 349975.29688095255, 1: 2876674.3017342356, 2: 827975.0650000006, 3: 4913329.426507118, 4: 605245.163706897, 5: 7431737.75197959, 6: 1154341.8745934067, 7: 1325611.1466724137, 8: 1167062.6884146344, 9: 78813.5207857143}}
{'diff': {0: 389236.3094642856, 1: 2919969.395930179, 2: 873295.801427419, 3: 4957163.9330507135, 4: 653377.0037568965, 5: 7479596.044428572, 6: 1214463.8978571433, 7: 1366351.4634890805, 8: 1200255.7743564018, 9: 112641.91081666667}}
{'diff': {0: 391681.69095, 1: 2921278.030853604, 2: 874417.996964516, 3: 4960328.984978635, 4: 658758.8998741381, 5: 7484168.382208164, 6: 1218278.5344219788, 7: 1367466.964590805, 8: 1200111.4596570123, 9: 113533.64980238095}}
{'diff': {0: 355994.5180714284, 1: 2882303.7541306294, 2: 835458.8338790324, 3: 4919442.302396014, 4: 610290.0786551724, 5: 7441912.343979592, 6: 1164700.055917583, 7: 1327737.2043103438, 8: 1169616.6454146332, 9: 81680.70286904761}}
{'diff': {0: 379893.7180714286, 1: 2913403.720793244, 2: 865857.7399225802, 3: 4948973.331188316, 4: 643761.719862069, 5: 7468621.204883674, 6: 1209897.9149901094, 7: 1359244.204440804, 8: 1192828.6090381108, 9: 104051.28336904761}}
{'diff': {0: 390466.6839142858, 1: 2923088.262698646, 2: 877156.1510145164, 3: 4962513.822048144, 4: 659759.9533551724, 5: 7483875.484744897, 6: 1222339.2461901105, 7: 1369121.0132643674, 8: 1201501.5448817061, 9: 113458.57306428571}}
{'diff': {0: 301792.62588095234, 1: 2854027.945333335, 2: 804759.8740564514, 3: 4876267.124210826, 4: 584088.0599310346, 5: 7378153.378530612, 6: 1133044.61306044, 7: 1291385.6421149436, 8: 1139054.1821890248, 9: 38275.36907142856}}
{'diff': {0: 387509.1658071429, 1: 2919049.8491373872, 2: 874219.6323653222, 3: 4955459.435102557, 4: 656559.3065396551, 5: 7476533.654826531, 6: 1217855.0112197807, 7: 1366842.1718931037, 8: 1198388.2114634141, 9: 108848.47544047613}}
{'diff': {0: 377328.5187738094, 1: 2907686.5556463962, 2: 861963.8367822578, 3: 4942903.962752138, 4: 642356.8619948275, 5: 7463152.797857141, 6: 1203804.631930769, 7: 1356454.3497155162, 8: 1189309.752909755, 9: 99476.27148809524}}
{'diff': {0: 352355.7500238095, 1: 2887318.768563064, 2: 841642.5822338712, 3: 4925029.717854701, 4: 621227.5312931032, 5: 7443790.6748775495, 6: 1183558.6595329673, 7: 1333697.2241666662, 8: 1172889.8671798778, 9: 81039.74188095241}}
{'diff': {0: 396255.3198571428, 1: 2926250.0441639633, 2: 880795.3943693547, 3: 4965277.919590886, 4: 663756.0494362068, 5: 7487330.063967346, 6: 1225360.306425824, 7: 1374148.3940419543, 8: 1204383.4553957311, 9: 117133.45492380955}}
{'diff': {0: 397275.22611428564, 1: 2928138.3937932434, 2: 882549.978358064, 3: 4967271.384024783, 4: 665063.7757241379, 5: 7489353.048779594, 6: 1227848.7195598893, 7: 1375612.8537936783, 8: 1205968.5550199081, 9: 118622.92846666674}}
{'diff': {0: 370638.9714999999, 1: 2901794.814063063, 2: 854231.343169355, 3: 4941840.968413107, 4: 636963.8949827587, 5: 7462906.844836734, 6: 1198474.5955769236, 7: 1349199.7593390818, 8: 1181772.3528810989, 9: 94418.88628571431}}
{'diff': {0: 399605.39451595227, 1: 2930519.3274677014, 2: 884866.901809758, 3: 4970067.843492109, 4: 668209.9673794828, 5: 7492181.322271633, 6: 1230438.6087753302, 7: 1377940.4613927014, 8: 1207999.2446168917, 9: 120766.5979569048}}
{'diff': {0: 394437.6273380953, 1: 2926444.621315316, 2: 880587.8419403222, 3: 4965842.826658971, 4: 663091.0379724137, 5: 7487427.719579593, 6: 1226653.0014609892, 7: 1373195.8957902302, 8: 1204177.9670981697, 9: 116665.88206190476}}
{'diff': {0: 343177.5738333332, 1: 2872438.88899099, 2: 824308.511145161, 3: 4901171.498498574, 4: 594996.441275862, 5: 7417912.784775511, 6: 1150261.9712527473, 7: 1323742.7629367814, 8: 1160229.847768293, 9: 70927.47897619048}}
{'diff': {0: 388380.7712333334, 1: 2919408.214353603, 2: 872090.4287451615, 3: 4957030.500496009, 4: 653652.7608896552, 5: 7478706.309169387, 6: 1210682.681124176, 7: 1365970.9027482753, 8: 1199850.2533893296, 9: 112281.24546190478}}
{'diff': {0: 397734.3032357143, 1: 2928578.1657990995, 2: 883142.2520741936, 3: 4967757.699845867, 4: 666066.6204482759, 5: 7489537.145657143, 6: 1228560.9616604394, 7: 1376307.6271563205, 8: 1206326.1817006094, 9: 118790.83264523809}}
{'diff': {0: 382516.58267857146, 1: 2915073.5680945935, 2: 869510.7518991937, 3: 4954054.122938737, 4: 651079.4144172415, 5: 7474328.030612243, 6: 1213478.4472478013, 7: 1363524.8940068972, 8: 1194637.4700762194, 9: 106180.7426238095}}
{'diff': {0: 395288.79071904765, 1: 2925967.5104626133, 2: 880203.2222838707, 3: 4964695.553390598, 4: 663391.0626017239, 5: 7486925.765212244, 6: 1224951.42912967, 7: 1373539.6626603457, 8: 1204264.0033243895, 9: 116594.66418571424}}
{'diff': {0: 397971.03177380946, 1: 2928499.596860811, 2: 882838.8586330643, 3: 4967899.803066952, 4: 665805.6550189656, 5: 7489992.297071429, 6: 1227996.4815417586, 7: 1376172.2323091957, 8: 1206288.5885036567, 9: 119011.36759404762}}
{'diff': {0: 381045.4717000001, 1: 2915758.7289301776, 2: 868614.6180701618, 3: 4952364.463031057, 4: 649488.6040396551, 5: 7473145.036408164, 6: 1211084.349763737, 7: 1359986.3620787358, 8: 1195206.9199817067, 9: 106315.4963142857}}
{'diff': {0: 396112.6919309524, 1: 2927023.3355063056, 2: 881553.0804177421, 3: 4965659.387115391, 4: 664581.2356241376, 5: 7487379.988112247, 6: 1226928.2231780214, 7: 1375081.4878034485, 8: 1204924.4063521333, 9: 117568.09009999997}}
{'diff': {0: 398791.83564142865, 1: 2929904.1134937378, 2: 884268.6928083871, 3: 4969186.882990996, 4: 667453.0766655172, 5: 7491095.65462857, 6: 1229856.0675498352, 7: 1377319.7854759197, 8: 1207308.6914243596, 9: 119888.01348333333}}
{'diff': {0: 361949.4825238095, 1: 2896682.3701126124, 2: 848862.5437822583, 3: 4928751.334897436, 4: 630220.5688913792, 5: 7450946.972428572, 6: 1187394.4575274729, 7: 1340303.0000775873, 8: 1179480.5218445128, 9: 87392.22891666667}}
{'diff': {0: 315083.9590238095, 1: 2875386.155256756, 2: 791020.9478145165, 3: 4919627.580308269, 4: 527800.8608620691, 5: 7418705.913040818, 6: 1038398.8350329669, 7: 1278070.7195321836, 8: 1177528.7164743906, 9: 74112.39018833333}}
{'diff': {0: 372749.6816428571, 1: 2896460.682382884, 2: 847202.8589435485, 3: 4930094.333652413, 4: 625970.5209655174, 5: 7459734.096877551, 6: 1180734.9652692305, 7: 1343552.4978419545, 8: 1181099.5920807915, 9: 96045.81380238094}}
{'diff': {0: 344613.2344047619, 1: 2879554.2198873875, 2: 832675.4379758065, 3: 4903486.329074071, 4: 607037.1537931036, 5: 7421040.479510205, 6: 1162536.2775054947, 7: 1323128.7494655175, 8: 1167686.5103018305, 9: 71892.5343452381}}
{'diff': {0: 384315.38414285716, 1: 2912584.135851351, 2: 868077.15266129, 3: 4948184.254348999, 4: 649068.8833655174, 5: 7468412.446755102, 6: 1210267.5453626376, 7: 1363363.9941091961, 8: 1193581.5346847544, 9: 105967.95393333334}}
{'diff': {0: 301436.47307142866, 1: 2814021.3400585586, 2: 745901.4201774193, 3: 4840460.746145298, 4: 474416.3661724136, 5: 7368423.201306123, 6: 956427.8998351648, 7: 1251712.683614943, 8: 1124866.8502560984, 9: 39000.96757142855}}
{'diff': {0: 350845.38038095244, 1: 2877748.116752253, 2: 830765.2659354841, 3: 4904564.910629633, 4: 609597.3515431035, 5: 7433322.860551022, 6: 1165465.3320219782, 7: 1328359.751505749, 8: 1164311.8769268298, 9: 75226.42738095239}}
{'diff': {0: 273791.3171666667, 1: 2806945.4198468463, 2: 722071.8942903227, 3: 4835423.34654701, 4: -74570571675091.14, 5: 7366856.7167755095, 6: 949178.8157032969, 7: 1234820.710781609, 8: 1113428.221018293, 9: 19590.516166666657}}
```

For each key 0-9, in my case, it is larger. I want an outcome where there is one dictionary with the lowest value for each key across all the different dictionaries.

so if, we have:

```
{'diff': {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 43, 4: -34, 5: 43, 6: 65, 7: 543, 8: 23, 9: 23}}
{'diff': {0: 6, 1: 3, 2: 8, 3: 78, 4: -23, 5: 54, 6: 76, 7: 43, 8: 234, 9: 54}}
```

Then I would expect:

```
{'diff': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 43, 4: -23, 5: 43, 6: 65, 7: 43, 8: 23, 9: 23}}
```

update: when you print the list of dicts, you get:

```
[{'diff': {0: 358438.3179047619, 1: 2877912.924419369, 2: 822017.9039274186, 3: 4914425.223282051, 4: 574184.9971827588, 5: 7432268.5341428565, 6: 1111639.5132252753, 7: 1322861.412610346, 8: 1179799.2592362808, 9: 87556.64146904761}}, {'diff': {0: 292811.4124761905, 1: 2831096.9336261265, 2: 760006.755798387, 3: 4868369.423293451, 4: 509515.30310344836, 5: 7390444.080714285, 6: 1028933.0801098899, 7: 1240273.4906724147, 8: 1138039.7093932922, 9: 43618.81660000001}}, {'diff': {0: 393148.40700238093, 1: 2923931.0134306327, 2: 878450.4552137096, 3: 4962539.102763245, 4: 660218.1550965513, 5: 7483527.590967346, 6: 1223029.819152747, 7: 1372622.6893804593, 8: 1202322.4719079277, 9: 113611.58858809523}}, {'diff': {0: 386402.65016666666, 1: 2916900.423062612, 2: 870947.0239475806, 3: 4954526.795990028, 4: 652106.3039551723, 5: 7475754.573836735, 6: 1212934.2664368134, 7: 1365836.4194977009, 8: 1196003.2297920743, 9: 108039.20073571429}}, {'diff': {0: 349975.29688095255, 1: 2876674.3017342356, 2: 827975.0650000006, 3: 4913329.426507118, 4: 605245.163706897, 5: 7431737.75197959, 6: 1154341.8745934067, 7: 1325611.1466724137, 8: 1167062.6884146344, 9: 78813.5207857143}}, {'diff': {0: 389236.3094642856, 1: 2919969.395930179, 2: 873295.801427419, 3: 4957163.9330507135, 4: 653377.0037568965, 5: 7479596.044428572, 6: 1214463.8978571433, 7: 1366351.4634890805, 8: 1200255.7743564018, 9: 112641.91081666667}}, {'diff': {0: 391681.69095, 1: 2921278.030853604, 2: 874417.996964516, 3: 4960328.984978635, 4: 658758.8998741381, 5: 7484168.382208164, 6: 1218278.5344219788, 7: 1367466.964590805, 8: 1200111.4596570123, 9: 113533.64980238095}}, {'diff': {0: 355994.5180714284, 1: 2882303.7541306294, 2: 835458.8338790324, 3: 4919442.302396014, 4: 610290.0786551724, 5: 7441912.343979592, 6: 1164700.055917583, 7: 1327737.2043103438, 8: 1169616.6454146332, 9: 81680.70286904761}}, {'diff': {0: 379893.7180714286, 1: 2913403.720793244, 2: 865857.7399225802, 3: 4948973.331188316, 4: 643761.719862069, 5: 7468621.204883674, 6: 1209897.9149901094, 7: 1359244.204440804, 8: 1192828.6090381108, 9: 104051.28336904761}}, {'diff': {0: 390466.6839142858, 1: 2923088.262698646, 2: 877156.1510145164, 3: 4962513.822048144, 4: 659759.9533551724, 5: 7483875.484744897, 6: 1222339.2461901105, 7: 1369121.0132643674, 8: 1201501.5448817061, 9: 113458.57306428571}}, {'diff': {0: 301792.62588095234, 1: 2854027.945333335, 2: 804759.8740564514, 3: 4876267.124210826, 4: 584088.0599310346, 5: 7378153.378530612, 6: 1133044.61306044, 7: 1291385.6421149436, 8: 1139054.1821890248, 9: 38275.36907142856}}, {'diff': {0: 387509.1658071429, 1: 2919049.8491373872, 2: 874219.6323653222, 3: 4955459.435102557, 4: 656559.3065396551, 5: 7476533.654826531, 6: 1217855.0112197807, 7: 1366842.1718931037, 8: 1198388.2114634141, 9: 108848.47544047613}}, {'diff': {0: 377328.5187738094, 1: 2907686.5556463962, 2: 861963.8367822578, 3: 4942903.962752138, 4: 642356.8619948275, 5: 7463152.797857141, 6: 1203804.631930769, 7: 1356454.3497155162, 8: 1189309.752909755, 9: 99476.27148809524}}, {'diff': {0: 352355.7500238095, 1: 2887318.768563064, 2: 841642.5822338712, 3: 4925029.717854701, 4: 621227.5312931032, 5: 7443790.6748775495, 6: 1183558.6595329673, 7: 1333697.2241666662, 8: 1172889.8671798778, 9: 81039.74188095241}}, {'diff': {0: 396255.3198571428, 1: 2926250.0441639633, 2: 880795.3943693547, 3: 4965277.919590886, 4: 663756.0494362068, 5: 7487330.063967346, 6: 1225360.306425824, 7: 1374148.3940419543, 8: 1204383.4553957311, 9: 117133.45492380955}}, {'diff': {0: 397275.22611428564, 1: 2928138.3937932434, 2: 882549.978358064, 3: 4967271.384024783, 4: 665063.7757241379, 5: 7489353.048779594, 6: 1227848.7195598893, 7: 1375612.8537936783, 8: 1205968.5550199081, 9: 118622.92846666674}}, {'diff': {0: 370638.9714999999, 1: 2901794.814063063, 2: 854231.343169355, 3: 4941840.968413107, 4: 636963.8949827587, 5: 7462906.844836734, 6: 1198474.5955769236, 7: 1349199.7593390818, 8: 1181772.3528810989, 9: 94418.88628571431}}, {'diff': {0: 399605.39451595227, 1: 2930519.3274677014, 2: 884866.901809758, 3: 4970067.843492109, 4: 668209.9673794828, 5: 7492181.322271633, 6: 1230438.6087753302, 7: 1377940.4613927014, 8: 1207999.2446168917, 9: 120766.5979569048}}, {'diff': {0: 394437.6273380953, 1: 2926444.621315316, 2: 880587.8419403222, 3: 4965842.826658971, 4: 663091.0379724137, 5: 7487427.719579593, 6: 1226653.0014609892, 7: 1373195.8957902302, 8: 1204177.9670981697, 9: 116665.88206190476}}, {'diff': {0: 343177.5738333332, 1: 2872438.88899099, 2: 824308.511145161, 3: 4901171.498498574, 4: 594996.441275862, 5: 7417912.784775511, 6: 1150261.9712527473, 7: 1323742.7629367814, 8: 1160229.847768293, 9: 70927.47897619048}}, {'diff': {0: 388380.7712333334, 1: 2919408.214353603, 2: 872090.4287451615, 3: 4957030.500496009, 4: 653652.7608896552, 5: 7478706.309169387, 6: 1210682.681124176, 7: 1365970.9027482753, 8: 1199850.2533893296, 9: 112281.24546190478}}, {'diff': {0: 397734.3032357143, 1: 2928578.1657990995, 2: 883142.2520741936, 3: 4967757.699845867, 4: 666066.6204482759, 5: 7489537.145657143, 6: 1228560.9616604394, 7: 1376307.6271563205, 8: 1206326.1817006094, 9: 118790.83264523809}}, {'diff': {0: 382516.58267857146, 1: 2915073.5680945935, 2: 869510.7518991937, 3: 4954054.122938737, 4: 651079.4144172415, 5: 7474328.030612243, 6: 1213478.4472478013, 7: 1363524.8940068972, 8: 1194637.4700762194, 9: 106180.7426238095}}, {'diff': {0: 395288.79071904765, 1: 2925967.5104626133, 2: 880203.2222838707, 3: 4964695.553390598, 4: 663391.0626017239, 5: 7486925.765212244, 6: 1224951.42912967, 7: 1373539.6626603457, 8: 1204264.0033243895, 9: 116594.66418571424}}, {'diff': {0: 397971.03177380946, 1: 2928499.596860811, 2: 882838.8586330643, 3: 4967899.803066952, 4: 665805.6550189656, 5: 7489992.297071429, 6: 1227996.4815417586, 7: 1376172.2323091957, 8: 1206288.5885036567, 9: 119011.36759404762}}, {'diff': {0: 381045.4717000001, 1: 2915758.7289301776, 2: 868614.6180701618, 3: 4952364.463031057, 4: 649488.6040396551, 5: 7473145.036408164, 6: 1211084.349763737, 7: 1359986.3620787358, 8: 1195206.9199817067, 9: 106315.4963142857}}, {'diff': {0: 396112.6919309524, 1: 2927023.3355063056, 2: 881553.0804177421, 3: 4965659.387115391, 4: 664581.2356241376, 5: 7487379.988112247, 6: 1226928.2231780214, 7: 1375081.4878034485, 8: 1204924.4063521333, 9: 117568.09009999997}}, {'diff': {0: 398791.83564142865, 1: 2929904.1134937378, 2: 884268.6928083871, 3: 4969186.882990996, 4: 667453.0766655172, 5: 7491095.65462857, 6: 1229856.0675498352, 7: 1377319.7854759197, 8: 1207308.6914243596, 9: 119888.01348333333}}, {'diff': {0: 361949.4825238095, 1: 2896682.3701126124, 2: 848862.5437822583, 3: 4928751.334897436, 4: 630220.5688913792, 5: 7450946.972428572, 6: 1187394.4575274729, 7: 1340303.0000775873, 8: 1179480.5218445128, 9: 87392.22891666667}}, {'diff': {0: 315083.9590238095, 1: 2875386.155256756, 2: 791020.9478145165, 3: 4919627.580308269, 4: 527800.8608620691, 5: 7418705.913040818, 6: 1038398.8350329669, 7: 1278070.7195321836, 8: 1177528.7164743906, 9: 74112.39018833333}}, {'diff': {0: 372749.6816428571, 1: 2896460.682382884, 2: 847202.8589435485, 3: 4930094.333652413, 4: 625970.5209655174, 5: 7459734.096877551, 6: 1180734.9652692305, 7: 1343552.4978419545, 8: 1181099.5920807915, 9: 96045.81380238094}}, {'diff': {0: 344613.2344047619, 1: 2879554.2198873875, 2: 832675.4379758065, 3: 4903486.329074071, 4: 607037.1537931036, 5: 7421040.479510205, 6: 1162536.2775054947, 7: 1323128.7494655175, 8: 1167686.5103018305, 9: 71892.5343452381}}, {'diff': {0: 384315.38414285716, 1: 2912584.135851351, 2: 868077.15266129, 3: 4948184.254348999, 4: 649068.8833655174, 5: 7468412.446755102, 6: 1210267.5453626376, 7: 1363363.9941091961, 8: 1193581.5346847544, 9: 105967.95393333334}}, {'diff': {0: 301436.47307142866, 1: 2814021.3400585586, 2: 745901.4201774193, 3: 4840460.746145298, 4: 474416.3661724136, 5: 7368423.201306123, 6: 956427.8998351648, 7: 1251712.683614943, 8: 1124866.8502560984, 9: 39000.96757142855}}, {'diff': {0: 350845.38038095244, 1: 2877748.116752253, 2: 830765.2659354841, 3: 4904564.910629633, 4: 609597.3515431035, 5: 7433322.860551022, 6: 1165465.3320219782, 7: 1328359.751505749, 8: 1164311.8769268298, 9: 75226.42738095239}}, {'diff': {0: 273791.3171666667, 1: 2806945.4198468463, 2: 722071.8942903227, 3: 4835423.34654701, 4: -74570571675091.14, 5: 7366856.7167755095, 6: 949178.8157032969, 7: 1234820.710781609, 8: 1113428.221018293, 9: 19590.516166666657}}]
```

Comment: Are all the dictionaries guaranteed to have all the keys?

Comment: @Barmar yes they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical reduce problem, so one approach is to use the built-in function [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce
def min_(x, y, key="diff"):
    return { key : { ki : min(xi, y[key][ki]) for ki, xi in x[key].items() } }

res = reduce(min_, data)
print(res)
```

**Output** *(for the given data)*

```
{'diff': {0: 273791.3171666667, 1: 2806945.4198468463, 2: 722071.8942903227, 3: 4835423.34654701, 4: -74570571675091.14, 5: 7366856.7167755095, 6: 949178.8157032969, 7: 1234820.710781609, 8: 1113428.221018293, 9: 19590.516166666657}}
```

As an alternative, you could use pandas, as below:

```
import pandas as pd
# assuming data is a list of dictionaries with the same format of the question
res = {"diff": pd.DataFrame(data=[d["diff"] for d in data]).min().to_dict()}
print(res)
```

**Output** *(using pandas)*

```
{'diff': {0: 273791.3171666667, 1: 2806945.4198468463, 2: 722071.8942903227, 3: 4835423.34654701, 4: -74570571675091.14, 5: 7366856.7167755095, 6: 949178.8157032969, 7: 1234820.710781609, 8: 1113428.221018293, 9: 19590.516166666657}}
```

Note that pandas is a (heavy) third-party library that needs to be [installed](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html).

Comment: actually I am sorry I just realize it's just a list of dictionaries..what format of are you using? a list of dicts?

Comment: Yes, a list of dicts

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a dictionary comprehension that calls `min()` across all the dictionaries in the list.

```
result = {'diff': 
    {key: min(item['diff'][key] for item in list_of_dicts) 
          for key in list_of_dicts[0]['diff']}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I just copy/pasted the dicts, but now I added them as a list of dicts, when I ran your code I got this errro - TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-0bc2b06bcb05> in <module>()
     16 result = {'diff': 
     17     {key: min(item['diff'][key] for item in list_of_dict) 
---> 18           for key in list_of_dict['diff'][0]}
     19 }
     20 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I updated the code with the output of printing the list of dicts

Comment: Sorry, I had things backwards. It should be `list_of_dicts[0]['diff']` to get all the keys

Answer (score 1):

A combination of zip and map can do this for you:

Input:

```
dicts = [ {'diff': {0: 358438.3179047619, 1: 2877912.924419369, 2: 822017.9039274186, 3: 4914425.223282051, 4: 574184.9971827588, 5: 7432268.5341428565, 6: 1111639.5132252753, 7: 1322861.412610346, 8: 1179799.2592362808, 9: 87556.64146904761}},
{'diff': {0: 292811.4124761905, 1: 2831096.9336261265, 2: 760006.755798387, 3: 4868369.423293451, 4: 509515.30310344836, 5: 7390444.080714285, 6: 1028933.0801098899, 7: 1240273.4906724147, 8: 1138039.7093932922, 9: 43618.81660000001}},
{'diff': {0: 393148.40700238093, 1: 2923931.0134306327, 2: 878450.4552137096, 3: 4962539.102763245, 4: 660218.1550965513, 5: 7483527.590967346, 6: 1223029.819152747, 7: 1372622.6893804593, 8: 1202322.4719079277, 9: 113611.58858809523}},
{'diff': {0: 386402.65016666666, 1: 2916900.423062612, 2: 870947.0239475806, 3: 4954526.795990028, 4: 652106.3039551723, 5: 7475754.573836735, 6: 1212934.2664368134, 7: 1365836.4194977009, 8: 1196003.2297920743, 9: 108039.20073571429}},
{'diff': {0: 349975.29688095255, 1: 2876674.3017342356, 2: 827975.0650000006, 3: 4913329.426507118, 4: 605245.163706897, 5: 7431737.75197959, 6: 1154341.8745934067, 7: 1325611.1466724137, 8: 1167062.6884146344, 9: 78813.5207857143}},
{'diff': {0: 389236.3094642856, 1: 2919969.395930179, 2: 873295.801427419, 3: 4957163.9330507135, 4: 653377.0037568965, 5: 7479596.044428572, 6: 1214463.8978571433, 7: 1366351.4634890805, 8: 1200255.7743564018, 9: 112641.91081666667}},
{'diff': {0: 391681.69095, 1: 2921278.030853604, 2: 874417.996964516, 3: 4960328.984978635, 4: 658758.8998741381, 5: 7484168.382208164, 6: 1218278.5344219788, 7: 1367466.964590805, 8: 1200111.4596570123, 9: 113533.64980238095}},
{'diff': {0: 355994.5180714284, 1: 2882303.7541306294, 2: 835458.8338790324, 3: 4919442.302396014, 4: 610290.0786551724, 5: 7441912.343979592, 6: 1164700.055917583, 7: 1327737.2043103438, 8: 1169616.6454146332, 9: 81680.70286904761}},
{'diff': {0: 379893.7180714286, 1: 2913403.720793244, 2: 865857.7399225802, 3: 4948973.331188316, 4: 643761.719862069, 5: 7468621.204883674, 6: 1209897.9149901094, 7: 1359244.204440804, 8: 1192828.6090381108, 9: 104051.28336904761}},
{'diff': {0: 390466.6839142858, 1: 2923088.262698646, 2: 877156.1510145164, 3: 4962513.822048144, 4: 659759.9533551724, 5: 7483875.484744897, 6: 1222339.2461901105, 7: 1369121.0132643674, 8: 1201501.5448817061, 9: 113458.57306428571}},
{'diff': {0: 301792.62588095234, 1: 2854027.945333335, 2: 804759.8740564514, 3: 4876267.124210826, 4: 584088.0599310346, 5: 7378153.378530612, 6: 1133044.61306044, 7: 1291385.6421149436, 8: 1139054.1821890248, 9: 38275.36907142856}},
{'diff': {0: 387509.1658071429, 1: 2919049.8491373872, 2: 874219.6323653222, 3: 4955459.435102557, 4: 656559.3065396551, 5: 7476533.654826531, 6: 1217855.0112197807, 7: 1366842.1718931037, 8: 1198388.2114634141, 9: 108848.47544047613}},
{'diff': {0: 377328.5187738094, 1: 2907686.5556463962, 2: 861963.8367822578, 3: 4942903.962752138, 4: 642356.8619948275, 5: 7463152.797857141, 6: 1203804.631930769, 7: 1356454.3497155162, 8: 1189309.752909755, 9: 99476.27148809524}},
{'diff': {0: 352355.7500238095, 1: 2887318.768563064, 2: 841642.5822338712, 3: 4925029.717854701, 4: 621227.5312931032, 5: 7443790.6748775495, 6: 1183558.6595329673, 7: 1333697.2241666662, 8: 1172889.8671798778, 9: 81039.74188095241}},
{'diff': {0: 396255.3198571428, 1: 2926250.0441639633, 2: 880795.3943693547, 3: 4965277.919590886, 4: 663756.0494362068, 5: 7487330.063967346, 6: 1225360.306425824, 7: 1374148.3940419543, 8: 1204383.4553957311, 9: 117133.45492380955}},
{'diff': {0: 397275.22611428564, 1: 2928138.3937932434, 2: 882549.978358064, 3: 4967271.384024783, 4: 665063.7757241379, 5: 7489353.048779594, 6: 1227848.7195598893, 7: 1375612.8537936783, 8: 1205968.5550199081, 9: 118622.92846666674}},
{'diff': {0: 370638.9714999999, 1: 2901794.814063063, 2: 854231.343169355, 3: 4941840.968413107, 4: 636963.8949827587, 5: 7462906.844836734, 6: 1198474.5955769236, 7: 1349199.7593390818, 8: 1181772.3528810989, 9: 94418.88628571431}},
{'diff': {0: 399605.39451595227, 1: 2930519.3274677014, 2: 884866.901809758, 3: 4970067.843492109, 4: 668209.9673794828, 5: 7492181.322271633, 6: 1230438.6087753302, 7: 1377940.4613927014, 8: 1207999.2446168917, 9: 120766.5979569048}},
{'diff': {0: 394437.6273380953, 1: 2926444.621315316, 2: 880587.8419403222, 3: 4965842.826658971, 4: 663091.0379724137, 5: 7487427.719579593, 6: 1226653.0014609892, 7: 1373195.8957902302, 8: 1204177.9670981697, 9: 116665.88206190476}},
{'diff': {0: 343177.5738333332, 1: 2872438.88899099, 2: 824308.511145161, 3: 4901171.498498574, 4: 594996.441275862, 5: 7417912.784775511, 6: 1150261.9712527473, 7: 1323742.7629367814, 8: 1160229.847768293, 9: 70927.47897619048}},
{'diff': {0: 388380.7712333334, 1: 2919408.214353603, 2: 872090.4287451615, 3: 4957030.500496009, 4: 653652.7608896552, 5: 7478706.309169387, 6: 1210682.681124176, 7: 1365970.9027482753, 8: 1199850.2533893296, 9: 112281.24546190478}},
{'diff': {0: 397734.3032357143, 1: 2928578.1657990995, 2: 883142.2520741936, 3: 4967757.699845867, 4: 666066.6204482759, 5: 7489537.145657143, 6: 1228560.9616604394, 7: 1376307.6271563205, 8: 1206326.1817006094, 9: 118790.83264523809}},
{'diff': {0: 382516.58267857146, 1: 2915073.5680945935, 2: 869510.7518991937, 3: 4954054.122938737, 4: 651079.4144172415, 5: 7474328.030612243, 6: 1213478.4472478013, 7: 1363524.8940068972, 8: 1194637.4700762194, 9: 106180.7426238095}},
{'diff': {0: 395288.79071904765, 1: 2925967.5104626133, 2: 880203.2222838707, 3: 4964695.553390598, 4: 663391.0626017239, 5: 7486925.765212244, 6: 1224951.42912967, 7: 1373539.6626603457, 8: 1204264.0033243895, 9: 116594.66418571424}},
{'diff': {0: 397971.03177380946, 1: 2928499.596860811, 2: 882838.8586330643, 3: 4967899.803066952, 4: 665805.6550189656, 5: 7489992.297071429, 6: 1227996.4815417586, 7: 1376172.2323091957, 8: 1206288.5885036567, 9: 119011.36759404762}},
{'diff': {0: 381045.4717000001, 1: 2915758.7289301776, 2: 868614.6180701618, 3: 4952364.463031057, 4: 649488.6040396551, 5: 7473145.036408164, 6: 1211084.349763737, 7: 1359986.3620787358, 8: 1195206.9199817067, 9: 106315.4963142857}},
{'diff': {0: 396112.6919309524, 1: 2927023.3355063056, 2: 881553.0804177421, 3: 4965659.387115391, 4: 664581.2356241376, 5: 7487379.988112247, 6: 1226928.2231780214, 7: 1375081.4878034485, 8: 1204924.4063521333, 9: 117568.09009999997}},
{'diff': {0: 398791.83564142865, 1: 2929904.1134937378, 2: 884268.6928083871, 3: 4969186.882990996, 4: 667453.0766655172, 5: 7491095.65462857, 6: 1229856.0675498352, 7: 1377319.7854759197, 8: 1207308.6914243596, 9: 119888.01348333333}},
{'diff': {0: 361949.4825238095, 1: 2896682.3701126124, 2: 848862.5437822583, 3: 4928751.334897436, 4: 630220.5688913792, 5: 7450946.972428572, 6: 1187394.4575274729, 7: 1340303.0000775873, 8: 1179480.5218445128, 9: 87392.22891666667}},
{'diff': {0: 315083.9590238095, 1: 2875386.155256756, 2: 791020.9478145165, 3: 4919627.580308269, 4: 527800.8608620691, 5: 7418705.913040818, 6: 1038398.8350329669, 7: 1278070.7195321836, 8: 1177528.7164743906, 9: 74112.39018833333}},
{'diff': {0: 372749.6816428571, 1: 2896460.682382884, 2: 847202.8589435485, 3: 4930094.333652413, 4: 625970.5209655174, 5: 7459734.096877551, 6: 1180734.9652692305, 7: 1343552.4978419545, 8: 1181099.5920807915, 9: 96045.81380238094}},
{'diff': {0: 344613.2344047619, 1: 2879554.2198873875, 2: 832675.4379758065, 3: 4903486.329074071, 4: 607037.1537931036, 5: 7421040.479510205, 6: 1162536.2775054947, 7: 1323128.7494655175, 8: 1167686.5103018305, 9: 71892.5343452381}},
{'diff': {0: 384315.38414285716, 1: 2912584.135851351, 2: 868077.15266129, 3: 4948184.254348999, 4: 649068.8833655174, 5: 7468412.446755102, 6: 1210267.5453626376, 7: 1363363.9941091961, 8: 1193581.5346847544, 9: 105967.95393333334}},
{'diff': {0: 301436.47307142866, 1: 2814021.3400585586, 2: 745901.4201774193, 3: 4840460.746145298, 4: 474416.3661724136, 5: 7368423.201306123, 6: 956427.8998351648, 7: 1251712.683614943, 8: 1124866.8502560984, 9: 39000.96757142855}},
{'diff': {0: 350845.38038095244, 1: 2877748.116752253, 2: 830765.2659354841, 3: 4904564.910629633, 4: 609597.3515431035, 5: 7433322.860551022, 6: 1165465.3320219782, 7: 1328359.751505749, 8: 1164311.8769268298, 9: 75226.42738095239}},
{'diff': {0: 273791.3171666667, 1: 2806945.4198468463, 2: 722071.8942903227, 3: 4835423.34654701, 4: -74570571675091.14, 5: 7366856.7167755095, 6: 949178.8157032969, 7: 1234820.710781609, 8: 1113428.221018293, 9: 19590.516166666657}}]
```

Output:

```
result = {'diff':dict(map(max,zip(*(d['diff'].items() for d in dicts))))}

print(result)

{'diff': {0: 399605.39451595227, 1: 2930519.3274677014, 
          2: 884866.901809758,   3: 4970067.843492109, 
          4: 668209.9673794828,  5: 7492181.322271633,
          6: 1230438.6087753302, 7: 1377940.4613927014, 
          8: 1207999.2446168917, 9: 120766.5979569048}}
```

*Note that this assumes that all 10 keys are always present and in the same order in every dictionary*

If the keys are not always present or not in the same order, you could do this:

```
result = {'diff':{k:max(d['diff'].get(k,0) for d in dicts) for k in range(10)}}
```